How can a God of classical theism be both omnipotent and unable to do evil (assuming divine simplicity)?
Consider a very powerful agent (call him Bob), who can do everything possible, except for turning on my TV. For Bob (maybe due to his nature) it is impossible to turn on my TV. Nobody would call Bob omnipotent, due to his lack of ability to turn on my TV.
Now consider God. According to what I've read about classical Christian theism, it is metaphysically impossible for God to sin due to his good divine nature. So how can God be omnipotent while not being able to sin, if Bob cannot be omnipotent while not being able to turn on my TV?
One way out is to deny that God lacks the powers. Maybe say something like “God has these powers but never actually uses them. It’s possible for him to do evil, but he doesn’t, he always freely does the good.” This gets one out of this objection but saddles one with 2 big issues: God's goodness can no longer be an essential property and the fact that this solution contradicts divine simplicity.
Are there any viable responses left for a classical theist that wishes to maintain divine simplicity?

I suppose that the Christian could merely respond that he is omnipotent given that he only follows his own nature. Regardless, there’s arguably deeper problems with the notion of divine simplicity, such as the existence of a supposedly all powerful being who’s completely immaterial and has no parts. It begs the question of how he does those things and how he can, in any real sense, even exist

But consider another agent called Bunny. Bunny can also only follow her nature, which dictates her to constantly be jumping. She is able to follow her nature without any hinderance. However, it would be a stretch to call Bunny omnipotent. Simple humans quite literally would be able to do more tasks than her.

@Syed, "...the existence of a supposedly all powerful being who’s completely immaterial and has no parts." Ordinary matter that we are able to detect actually forms a very small percentage of what we know is really out there...

BTW, DV for the glaring omission of frame of reference and definition of evil.

I think this is just a rephrasing of Heinlein's "God is omniscient, omnipotent, and omnibenevolent. It says so right here on the label. If you can believe all three at once, I have a bridge I would like to sell you. Cash only, and small denominations please." (Quoted from memory; the original is in The Notebooks Of Lazarus Long if you want an authoritative version.) Note that this question, as far as I know, only applies to Christianity's God, and maybe not all versions of him; he could be all three and just not feel compelled to intervene, benevolence!=activism.

The Doctrine of Divine Simplicity denies all potentiality in God. See: Pure act. Omnipotence interpreted as an infinite list of unactualized potentialities is thus flatly denied by proponents of DDS. Alternative interpretations of omnipotence must be posited if one wishes to conform to a dogma of omnipotence while holding DDS. For example, in Roman Catholicism:

[A]lthough God does not bring into external being all that He is able to
accomplish, His power must not be understood as passing through
successive stages before its effect is accomplished. The activity of
God is simple and eternal, without evolution or change. The transition
from possibility to actuality or from act to potentiality occurs only
in creatures. When it is said that God can or could do a thing, the
terms are not to be understood in the sense in which they are applied
to created causes. [...] 'Power', says St. Thomas [Aquinas], 'is not
attributed to God as a thing really different from His Knowledge and
Will, but as something expressed by a different concept, since power
means that which executes the command of the will and the advice of
the intellect. These three (viz., intellect, will, power), coincide with one another in God.'

And as regards sin,

Man‘s power of preferring evil to good is a sign not of strength, but of infirmity, since it involves the liability to be overcome by unworthy motives; not the exercise but the restraint of that power adds to the freedom and vigor of the will.
(J. A. McHugh)


The most simple out is probably to add "definer of morals" to gods attributes, as is often actually done. So what god does is by definition good, like "what would Jesus do?". So god couldn't do evil because even if he gets fully old testament on folks that is good... by definition...
Also you as well have the power to take the device in front of you and thrust it against the nearest wall, you won't do it. So not doing something doesn't have to be a necessity it can also be a choice that is done voluntarily. And why would that contradict divine simplicity more than having an omnipotent being in the first place?

I feel I have to repeat that traditional mom-ism here: "Just because you can do something doesn't mean you ought to do it."
Omnipotence in this sense is probably better interpreted as sine restrictione (without restriction). An omnipotent being can do anything possible, but a wise being won't do things contrary to its principled understanding, as a matter of choice. There's an interesting but unfortunate tendency to think of God(s) and higher beings as though they are ethical mechanisms that must behave according to some predetermined set of goodie-two-shoes rules, not as beings that make moral choices according to sophisticated understandings.
I see the same confusion in Eastern thinking, incidentally. People tend to think about enlightenment as though it were freedom from the karma of the external world, leaving the enlightened being detached and incapable of worldly action. But in fact, enlightenment means freedom from internal karma as well, where an enlightened being is free to act without the compulsions and cravings that lead to misadventure.
It seems to me that people have a hard time escaping the notion that man is made in a divine image; even people who see man as deterministic tend to re-conceive the divine as divinely deterministic. Few people are comfortable with the great unknown…

The other end run around this is that if God does it, then by definition it is not evil. That wouldn't make sense for humans but hey, God gets to set the rules.

God would have free will.  It would be fully capable of doing evil if it so chose, but would not choose to do so because of it's nature.
God's actions are fully capable of changing it's nature in such a circumstance which means that God does indeed have the potential to do evil.  At that moment God would then be evil.

1. Grammar

You say you dont believe in God; yet you believe in grammar
Nietzsche

Classical theism almost by def. is Christian theism and Nietzsche intuited with his characteristic perspicacity that our commitments to grammar override our commitments to theology whatever they may be, and it makes little difference whether we belong to the theist or non/a/anti-theist camp. The frame doesn't change. And Christianity is hopelessly stuck in the God-is-a-noun mold. Widen the theism-net and you'll find verb/adjective/adverb possibilites

It is a fundamental characteristic of the Abrahamic God that 'He' is a noun
In native American God is a verb
For Plato the “forms” are really adjectives reaching deification for 'the form of the Good'
In the Bhagavad Gita there is an implication that God is an adverb, see chapter 10

Of course the question of omnipotence then becomes a non sequitur or trivial when God is not a noun.
2. Ontology
Even more fundamental than the grammar question is the modality one.
The Christian God is invariably A contingent being (person).
The Hindu God by contrast is necessary Being (no indefinite article).
To be fair there have been important Christians, most notably Anselm, who understood this that if God is God he (she/it) must be and not just hapoen to be so by Biblical happenstance. But this never became mainstream.
Like with the question of grammar if the modality of the status of God's existence becomes necessary the question of omnipotence must be subsumed by a more apophatic negation of all (further) modality
